# To get Max count from Hibernate Group By

Tags: hibernate, projection, hibernate-criteria

How to implement below code in hibernate using criteria and projection :

```
select CUSTOMER_NO,count(*) as max_count
from table
group by CUSTOMER_NO
having count(*) in 
(
select 
max(count) 
from 
(
select count(*) as count,CUSTOMER_NO
from table
group by CUSTOMER_NO
) t1
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query can be change to: `select CUSTOMER_NO, count(*) as count from temp.t group by CUSTOMER_NO order by count desc limit 1;`

And criteria for the same is:

```
    criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.groupProperty("CUSTOMER_NO")).add(Projections.rowCount(), "count"));
    criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("count"));
    criteria.setMaxResults(1);
    return criteria.list();
```

Comment: criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.property("CUSTOMER_NO")).add(Projections.rowCount()).add(Projections.sqlGroupProjection("CUSTOMER_NO", "CUSTOMER_NO having count(*) = (select max(tbl.c) as count from (select count( * ) as c from temp.t group by CUSTOMER_NO) as tbl)", new String[] {}, new Type[] {})));

Comment: select count(*) as count, CUSTOMER_NO from temp.t group by CUSTOMER_NO having count(*) = (select max(tbl.c) as count from (select count(*) as c from temp.t group by CUSTOMER_NO) as tbl);